# How to test component properly using UseState

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am new to tests in react and I don't know how to properly mock the useState value to properly cover the lines that uses the boolean as a parameter to return the component

React Code

```
import React from "react";
import { InputGroup, Input, Button, Spinner, Center } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import movieAPI from "../../services/movieAPI";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import styles from "./index.module.css";
export const Search = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [movie, setMovie] = React.useState("");
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = React.useState(false);
  const handleClick = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    const data = await movieAPI.fetchMovieByTitle(movie);
    setLoading(false);
    navigate(`/movie/${data.Title}`, { state: data });
  };
  return isLoading ? (
    <Center>
      <Spinner
        data-testid="spinner"
        className={styles.verticalCenter}
        thickness="6px"
        speed="1.0s"
        emptyColor="gray.200"
        color="green.500"
        size="xl"
      />
    </Center>
  ) : (
    <InputGroup m={2} p={2}>
      <Input onChange={(e) => setMovie(e.target.value)} placeholder="Search" />
      <Button onClick={handleClick}>Search</Button>
    </InputGroup>
  );
};
```

How can I mock the property loading in order to cover the specific line of the spinner component?
down below is my attempt to test the Spinner code

```
import { render, fireEvent, RenderResult } from "@testing-library/react";
import { Search } from "../../components/search/search";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import React from "react";
describe("search.tsx", () => {
  let isLoading = false;
  let setLoading = jest.fn();
  let container: RenderResult<
    typeof import("@testing-library/dom/types/queries"),
    HTMLElement,
    HTMLElement
  >;
  jest.mock("react", () => {
    return {
      ...jest.requireActual("react"),
      useState: () => ({
        isLoading: isLoading,
        setLoading: setLoading,
      }),
    };
  });
  beforeEach(() => {
    container = render(
      <Router>
        <Search />
      </Router>
    );
  });
  it("should render spinner", async () => {
    setLoading.mockImplementation((data) => {
      isLoading = data;
    });
    setLoading(true);
    console.log(await container.findByTestId("spinner"));
  });
});
```

Comment: it is not recommended to mock useState. Could you please provide the code snippets

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Samantha just added the code

Comment: Don't test implementation details. I think `useState` would be considered an implementation detail for a UI component. Instead, test that your component reaches the desired visual state via user interactions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A component is like a black box for testing.
It has two inputs: props and user interaction. Based on those it renders something. you should not mock `useState`. Your test would look like this:

You can mock other dependencies like localStorage and or rest api calls. But no internal component implementation.

Your test should look like this, written in pseudo code

```js
it("Should show loader while searching for movies", () => {
   // mock the API to return promise which never resolves

   // render component
   // input some search data
   // click the search button
   
   // expect the loader to be visible
});

it("Should reflect text base on user input,", () => {
  // render component
  // input some search data "Start"

  // expect searchInput.text to have value = "Start"
})
```